# What does this entry in the editor stats mean?

Tags: support, review

I approved a suggested edit on meta, and I noticed that the editor stats shown for the approved edit show the following data.

[image: screenshot]

The second entry doesn't report any status.
When I looked at the review page, the edit I approved was the only pending approval; the second entry is then not a proposed edit that still needs to be approved.

What does the second entry report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the one you're looking at.

Compare the [editor stats section of his first edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2009) with the [editor stats section of his second edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2010).

The reason they have the same name is because one is an edit to a question and the other is an edit to an answer to that same question.

You can look at any suggested edit and notice that the one you're looking at has no status in either the editor or reviewer stats.

Comment: I was expecting that the entry on the top was the most recent one; if I recall correctly, that is how it worked before.